# What is wrong with this proof that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} f(x)\sin(nx)dx=0$

Tags: limits, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

I lost 18 out of 20 points on this question and I'm not sure why.

> Suppose $f$ is continuous on $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. What is the $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int\limits_0^\frac{\pi}{2} f(x)\sin(nx)\,dx$? Prove your claim. Hint: Use Stone-Weierstrass

Here is my proof:

> Let $\epsilon > 0$ and consider $\mathcal{A}= \left\{\sum_{n=1}^Na_n\sin(nx)\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}, a_n\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$ on $\left[\epsilon,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.
>
> $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra of functions which vanishes only at $x=0$, and which separates points, since $\sin(x)$ is a 1-1 function on $\left[\epsilon,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. Therefore, by the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem, there is a sequence $s_n$ of functions of $\mathcal{A}$ that converges uniformly to $f(x)$ on $\left[\epsilon,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ for every $\epsilon>0$.
>
> Since $s_n$ is a series that converges uniformly to $f(x)$, there is a $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that when $N<m<n$ we have $|\sum_{m=i}^na_i\sin(ix)|<\epsilon|a_n|$, and when $n=m+1$, $|a_n\sin(nx)|\leq\epsilon |a_n|$ for $x\in\left[\epsilon,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$
>
> Therefore
>
> $$|\sin(nx)|\leq\epsilon$$
>
> $$|f(x)\sin(nx)|\leq|f(x)|\epsilon=|f(x)\epsilon|$$
>
> $$\int\limits_\epsilon^\frac{\pi}{2} |f(x)\sin(nx)|\,dx\leq \int\limits_\epsilon^\frac{\pi}{2} |f(x)\epsilon|\,dx = \epsilon\left[F\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-F(\epsilon)\right],$$
>
> where $F'(x)=f(x)$.
>
> By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $\int\limits_x^\frac{\pi}{2} f(t)\sin(nt)\,dt$ is continuous, so for sufficiently large $n$,
>
> $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^\frac{\pi}{2} |f(x)\sin(nx)|\,dx=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\epsilon\left[F\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-F(0)\right]= 0\left[F\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-F(0)\right]=0.$$
>
> So $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} f(x)\sin(nx)\,dx=0$.

Comment: This is the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma - in a nutshell, stating that Fourier coefficients decay to zero.

Comment: Can you use the fact that the Fourier coefficients of an $L^2$ function are square summable?

Comment: @carmichael561 no, essentially we can use chapters 1-8 of baby Rudin

Comment: Your third paragraph is where it went seriously wrong. Check Stone-Weierstrass again and make sure you understand it.

Comment: @i707107 the third paragraph is from the Cauchy Criterion for uniform convergence.

Comment: although, I realize now that something is still wrong because $|sin(nx)|=1$ for some values of x

Comment: Why do you think that is an algebra?

Comment: @zhw I thought it was an algebra because it is a subset of the trigonometry polynomials, which is an algebra. But now I don't think that it is closed under multiplication. Oops.

Comment: Right. For example $\sin^2 x$ is even so it can't be a linear combination of odd functions, even on an interval to the right of $0.$

Comment: Thanks. Combined with $\sin(nx)\leq\epsilon$ I should have realized this is actually a proof that the set isn't an algebra

Comment: I think the appropriate sub-algebra to take here are step functions.

Comment: Why not use the whole space of trigonometric polynomials $A =\{ \sum_{k=-n}^{n}a_ne^{ikx}\}$ as your algebra?